# How to open Apple Maps focusing on the services tab ? (URL scheme)

Tags: ios, service, url-scheme, apple-maps

I am opening the Apple's Maps application from mine by using universal links.

I implemented them to open the application with different transport type (by car, by foot and by public transit). I also would like to open it and focus the user's view on the services tab, but couldn't find a way to do so.

[image]

Any idea ?
I thank you in advance for your time and your response !
Best regards,

Comment: Tried to edit my post since I forgot the salute part, but it doesn't update it. :'(

Comment: You would set this in launchOptions using MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, but it only appears to support MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking, MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit, MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDefault (users current preference).  There is no option for the last tab (Ride / Services).

Comment: I was expecting this response and hoped to see someone that will say otherwise. ^^' If you write down a formal answer and if no one else would come with a solution, I could mark yours it as the accepted one. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set this in `launchOptions` using `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey`, but it only currently supports:

- `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving`
- `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking`
- `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit`
- `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDefault //Users current preference`

There is no option (**Swift 4.2**) to select the last tab (for Ride / Services).  It is likely that as this is a recently added feature, Apple have not yet updated the class.  I do not know of a workaround.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/directions_mode_values

For the sake of completeness this is how you would open it:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.331686, -122.030656)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate))
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit])
```